# How to access multiple rows in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridiview which gives me a output of 20 members in a list. Now i want to pay salary to only specific person and to only to those persons whose checkbox is checked i tried some thing like this a follows :

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow GVR in GridView.Rows)
        {
            if (GVR.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)GVR.FindControl("MemberCheck");
                    if (c.Checked)
                    {

                        string DividendAmount = GridView.Rows[0].Cells[5].Text;
                        string MOP = GridView.Rows[0].Cells[4].Text;
                    }
            }
        }
     }
```

But the problem is by this code i can access only any one particular row but what if i have selected n rows ???

Comment: If the question is not clear please let me know

Comment: Aren't you accessing each row one at a time with the foreach loop?  Are you saying you want to access other rows in the table besides the one set to the variable GVR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean?

```
string DividendAmount = GVR.Cells[5].Text;
string MOP = GVR.Cells[4].Text;
```